# Importing complex settings from VSCode to GoLand

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, hotkeys, ideavim

I have been setting up VSCode for myself for a very long time. Here is an example of my personal settings:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f shift+-",
        "command": "workbench.action.splitEditor"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f -",
        "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorOrthogonal"
    },
```

I'm splitting the screen <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>, <kbd>_</kbd> (`Ctrl +F` is prefix).

Can I do something like this in GoLand? I have not found the possibility of a hotkey prefix.

I also use vim plugin in VSCode. I like that I can navigate using <kbd>jk</kbd> between folders and files in VSCode explorer. Can IdeaVim help me with this?

Comment: *"I'm splitting the screen `Ctrl + F, _` (`Ctrl +F` is prefix). Can I do something like this in GoLand"* Yes -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#add-keyboard-shortcut -- see #3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It calls "Second stroke shortcut". You can configure them in IDE settings (Preferences | Keymap).
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#add-keyboard-shortcut